# How to terminate input process after getting a negative integer, and also finding the second largest number?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, counter

So my task is to write a C program that repeatedly gets non-negative integers from user input. And when a negative integer is obtained, the value is discarded and the input process is terminated immediately. Then, I need to print the second largest number.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int counter, a[counter];
    for (int counter = 0; counter++;) {
        scanf("%d", &a[counter]);
        if (a[counter]<0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    max1 = max2 = INT_MIN;
    for (i=0; i<counter; i++;) {
       if (a[i]>max2 && a[i]<max1) {
           max2 = max1;
           max1 = arr[i];
       }
       else if (a[i]>max2 && a[i]<max1) {
           max2 = a[i];
    }
    
    printf(max2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

So first, I used a for loop to create the user input process. I did the if statement to terminate the process if the user inputs a negative number. Then I'm not sure what max1 = max2 = INT_MIN is for, I found it from a website. Then there's another for loop which is supposed to check for the second largest number.

I got a whole load of errors and I have no idea what I did wrong. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of problems in your code.

For example, your first for() loop is bad code. Why would you do something so complex with your exit condition boolean being `counter++`?

Why use an array when you can just store 2 values?

Why such boolean logic?

Also: `max1 = max2 = INT_MIN`

Neither max1 or max2 are defined. Also, no need to assign them to INT_MIN, just -1 is enough.

Here is a simple way to do that

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int max = -1;
    int second_max = -1;
    int user_input = 0;
    do {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &user_input);
        if (user_input > max)
            max = user_input;
        else if (user_input > second_max)
            second_max = user_input;

    } while (user_input >= 0);
    if (second_max == -1) exit(1);  // Error, user only put one positive number
    printf("Max is : %d, second max is : %d\n", max, second_max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your forgot to mention: `int counter, a[counter];` which defines a VLA when `counter` is uninitialized.